# Google Places API INVALID_REQUEST with no types attribute

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

At least this one should be easy for you to verify. This request returns an `INVALID_REQUEST`:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=51.509980,-0.133700&sensor=true&rankby=distance&key=[api_key]

But this one works (exactly the same but with a `types` parameter):

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=51.509980,-0.133700&sensor=true&rankby=distance&key=[api_key]&types=food

In the documentation it says that types is not a required parameter so is it a bug in their API?

Comment: I was getting the same error because my location object was null sometimes. So location was not added to URL. Might help someone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not a bug but an expected behaviour (inconsistent behaviour I believe but anyways). For those who are interested, I got my answer here: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5456

> - distance. This option sorts results in ascending order by their distance from the specified location. Ranking results by distance will
>     set a fixed search radius of 50km. One or more of keyword, name, or
>     types is required.