# Bad request places api Go

Tags: go, google-places-api

I'm using [google places api](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-go) to retrieve all results related with a  search, so this is the things that I'm doing

```golang
type Places struct {
    ApiKey string
    Cx string
    c *maps.Client
}

func NewPlacesSearch(apiKey, cx string ) (*Places,error) {
    c, err := maps.NewClient(maps.WithAPIKey(apiKey))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    p := &Places{ApiKey:apiKey, Cx: cx, c:c}
    return p,nil
}

// Search returns all the results respect a keywords
func (p *Places) Search(search string) ([]*maps.PlacesSearchResponse, error) {
    results := make([]*maps.PlacesSearchResponse,0)
    search = url.QueryEscape(search)
    response, err := p.makeSearch(search, "")
    if err != nil {
        return results, err
    }
    results = append(results,response)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n",response)
    done:= false
    if response.NextPageToken == "" {
        done = true
    }
    for !done {
        response, err = p.makeSearch(search, response.NextPageToken)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("fatal error: %s", err)
        }
        fmt.Println(response)
        if response.NextPageToken == "" {
            done = true
        }
        results = append(results,response)
    }
    return results, nil
}

func (p *Places) makeSearch(search, token  string) (*maps.PlacesSearchResponse,error) {
    r := &maps.TextSearchRequest{Query: search ,PageToken:token}
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n",r)
    response, err:= p.c.TextSearch(context.Background(),r)
    if err != nil {
        return  &maps.PlacesSearchResponse{}, err
    }
    return &response,nil
}
```

Im trying to iterate over all the pagination from google results, as you can see in first request inside of `Search` function

```golang
response, err := p.makeSearch(search, "")
```

The request is

```golang
{
    Query:my+text+to+search
    Location:<nil> 
    Radius:0 
    Language: 
    MinPrice: 
    MaxPrice: 
    OpenNow:false 
    Type: 
    PageToken:
 }
```

But when I try to do the second request (inside in the loop) I get a message

```
fatal error: maps: INVALID_REQUEST -
```

The second request looks like:

```golang
{
    Query:my+text+to+search
    Location:<nil> 
    Radius:0 
    Language: 
    MinPrice: 
    MaxPrice: 
    OpenNow: false 
    Type: 
    PageToken: CuQB3AAAAMy72z91....
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The places file for TextSearch states that `// PageToken returns the next 20 results from a previously run search. Setting a PageToken parameter will execute a search with the same parameters used previously — all parameters other than PageToken will be ignored.`  While the documentation doesn't state that it's *invalid* to include the other parameters, it may in fact be.  Have you tried conditionally setting the `Query` field only if the `PageToken` is empty (so the pagination queries only have the `PageToken` and not the `Query`)?

Comment: @Kaedys  I get the same result, if  I do a request without a `Query` when is present the `PageToken`

Comment: Try adding a `types` parameter. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16826829/google-places-api-invalid-request-with-no-types-attribute and https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5456